# How to create jar testng

Tags: ant, testng

We are using ANT as build and TestNG for execution.

if it would not been testNG then i know how to create JAR. in the below ANT  i would have given MAIN class file but i dont know in case of TESTNG what should i provide in manifest

```
<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}\ServerSpaceAlert.jar" basedir="${build.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="test.MAIN" />
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```

Can somebody please help me.

Thanks
S

Comment: Not completely sure I understand your question but let me make a few comments that might help.  1) It seems like a couple problems here.  First, how to create an executable jar, which looks fairly correct.  YOu need the main class specified in the manifest.  2) Not really sure where TestNG comes into play with creating this jar?  3) Do you  have some test cases you are trying run that exercise the ServerSpaceAlert.jar?

Comment: we dont have main class file. we are using testng to run out programs.[http://testng.org/doc/index.html] 3.ServerSpaceAlert.jar is the name which i want to give to my jar.

Comment: Can we separate out the two things: 1) creating the jar - which looks okay.  2) Running TestNG should be very similiar to running JUnit.  Check http://testng.org/doc/ant.html for more info on running the test cases.